# How can I kill all threads spawned by Parallel.ForEach from my main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, kill, plinq

Here's the scenario:

I have a Windows Service that's running. `OnStart()` it sets up a timer that will call a function (let's call it `ProcessEvent()`). The code inside `ProcessEvent` is a critical section, so only one thread can do the following:

```
private void ProcessEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock(lockObj)
    {
        string[] list = GetList();
        Parallel.ForEach(list, item => { ProcessItem(item) });
    }
}
```

`ProcessItem` can potentially take a long time.

Now when the service is stopped my `OnStop()` currently just stops and disposes the timer. However I noticed that even after service is stopped there are threads that are still running `ProcessItem()`.

So how can I kill all running threads spawned by this program (mainly the ones spawned by the `Parallel.ForEach` but also any that are waiting on the lock in `ProcessEvent`)?

I know that had I created the thread myself I could set `isBackground` to true and it will all get killed when process dies but I don't create these threads manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) structure. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256691.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) for more information.

```
// Setup the cancellation mechanism.
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var po = new ParallelOptions();
po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;

// Run the enumerator in parallel.
Parallel.ForEach(list, po, 
  (item) =>
  {
    ProcessItem(item);
    po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  });

// Call Cancel to make Parallel.ForEach throw.
// Obviously this must done from another thread.
cts.Cancel();
```

Comment: Sweet! While I like spender's solution this one is a little cleaner since I don't have to maintain a flag myself.

Comment: Does this `cts.Cancel()` cancel all threads or just the current, so it cancel itself?

Comment: @anmarti: It will cause any thread that is "listening" to it to end itself (assuming the code adheres to the cancellation protocol correctly).

Answer (score 5):

Look into the overloads of [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) that take a delegate with a [ParallelLoopState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.aspx) parameter. Check a flag in the body to see if execution should continue, otherwise kill it:

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, (item, pls) => { 
    if(quit)pls.Stop();
    else
        ProcessItem(item);
});
```

Comment: What is `quit` in this case? Just a flag I set `OnStop()`?

Comment: Wonderful thanks! What about the threads spawned by the timer that are waiting on the lock in `ProcessEvent`? Are those automatically killed?

Comment: This just won't start any new threads; it won't help with threads that are already started.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx